# Why does conditional formatting disables when selecting a value from the slicer in Power Bi?

Tags: powerbi, conditional-formatting, powerbi-desktop

I am using matrix visual in power Bi report. I have applied 3 slicers and also done background conditional formatting based on "rules" on my each "Values" kept in the visual, however while selecting any of the slicer option, the conditional formatting behaves in the wrong way on the matrix visual. any idea why is this happening? Also, what can be done to make this right?

Comment: Can you show some sample data and your current presentation?

Comment: @R_R just figured it out and posted an answer!

Comment: Nice to see you find the solution. You can also accept your own answer so that other people can understand how you solve the issue :)

Comment: @R_R okay, never knew that. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

So my actual data type was a whole number which I was converting to a percentage by clicking the % sign. While applying conditional formatting, I was choosing rule based formatting and inside that I was choosing "percent" instead of "value".
Power BI is taking into consideration the actual data (which was in value) and not the converted percentage while doing conditional formatting.